# Return a value type of element from a function in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

This is my XML

```
<report>
    <format-inputs>
        <narrative-entity-ids>
            <entity id="28495795" type-cdf-meaning="DIAGNOSES"/>
            <entity id="28495741" type-cdf-meaning="DIAGNOSES"/>
            <entity id="28495471" type-cdf-meaning="DIAGNOSES"/>
        </narrative-entity-ids>
    </format-inputs>
</report>
```

I am creating a function in commonFunction.xslt

```
<xsl:function name="cdocfx:createEntityIdList" >
        <xsl:param name="formatInputsNodes"/>

        <xsl:if test="fn:exists(n:report/n:format-inputs)"
        <xsl:variable name="entityIdList" as="element()*">
            <xsl:for-each select="$formatInputsNodes/n:narrative-entity-ids/n:entity">
                <Item><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
       </xsl:if>

        <xsl:copy-of select="$entityIdList"/>

    </xsl:function>
```

I am calling this function in other xslt file where commonFunction.xslt was included

```
<xsl:variable name="entityIdList" select="cdocfx:createEntityIdList(n:report/n:format-inputs)"/>

</xsl:variable>
```

My question is variable entityIdList should be value type of element but it is having the document-node type how can i achieve this ??

Comment: while i call this function should received that variable value type as element only but its converting into document-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT you have, output you want and the one you get together with any exact error messages you have encountered.

I am currently not sure I understand what you want to achieve, if you construct a variable of type `element()*` you seem to want to construct a sequence of element nodes. Any `xsl:value-of` however will only output the string values of the selected items in a text node so it is not clear why you first construct elements if you only want to output string values. If you construct nodes and want to output them use `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:sequence`, not `xsl:value-of`.

To show two examples of writing a function that returns a sequence of elements (i.e. whose result is of type `element()*`) I have set up https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtE which has two functions

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:ex1">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="element()*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$input">
          <item>{ @id }</item>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="mf:ex2">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="element()*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="elements" as="element()*">
          <xsl:for-each select="$input">
              <item>{ @id }</item>
          </xsl:for-each>          
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence select="$elements"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

the first simply directly constructs some result elements in the function body, that way the result is a sequence of element nodes. The second function uses your approach of constructing a sequence of elements nodes in a variable, the proper way to return that variable value then from the function is to use `xsl:sequence`.

It is not clear at which position of the posted code you think are dealing with a `document-node()` node.

Note also that

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="fn:exists($formatInputsNodes/n:narrative-entity-ids)">
            <xsl:for-each select="$formatInputsNodes/n:narrative-entity-ids/n:entity">
                <Item><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
```

can be simplified to

```
      <xsl:for-each select="$formatInputsNodes/n:narrative-entity-ids/n:entity">
             <Item><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></Item>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

As you have now presented an XML input that is at least well-formed and some XSLT snippets (that are unfortunately not well-formed and seem to use a namespace although the XML input shown doesn't use one) here is an attempt to morph that into a working sample

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:cdocfx="http://example.com/cdox-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:function name="cdocfx:createEntityIdList" >
    <xsl:param name="formatInputsNodes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="entityIdList" as="element()*">
        <xsl:for-each select="$formatInputsNodes/narrative-entity-ids/entity">
            <Item><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></Item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>


    <xsl:copy-of select="$entityIdList"/>

  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:variable name="entityIdList" select="cdocfx:createEntityIdList(report/format-inputs)"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="$entityIdList instance of element()*, $entityIdList" separator=", "/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTW/1

Output there for the check `$entityIdList instance of element()*` is `true` so I am not sure why you say you have a document node.

Comment: here is the xml

Comment: here is the xml 

<format-inputs>
        <narrative-entity-ids>
            <entity id="28495795" type-cdf-meaning="DIAGNOSES"/>
            <entity id="28495741" type-cdf-meaning="DIAGNOSES"/>
            <entity id="28495471" type-cdf-meaning="DIAGNOSES"/>
        </narrative-entity-ids>
    </format-inputs>

Comment: i want to create a entityidlist of value type element . while calling this function i get the value type as document node .

Comment: Please edit your question and provide well-formatted and minimal but complete code samples demonstrating the issue, allowing us to reproduce it. If you use namespaces in the XSLT then we need to see XML with proper namespace declarations. But in any case the use of `xsl:value-of` to return any item from a function does not work, `xsl:value-of` constructs a text node, to return some value as constructed use `xsl:sequence` or to return a copy use `xsl:copy-of`.

Comment: there is commonfunction.xslt there i define the function . calling this function in another xslt (wherein commonfunction.xslt is included in the calling xslt file)

i should receive that entityidList value type to be element only how can i achieve this is my question

Comment: You seem to changing your question once it has an answer. If you construct a sequence of type `element()*` and process several elements to construct `Item` elements for each, why do suddenly only want exactly one element, as that is what `element()` means? It is still not clear what you want, as I said, minimal but complete and well-formatted samples of XML input, XSLT you have, result you get and the one you want would help.

Comment: I did not change the question i made the question more simpler to understand

Comment: I have added some attempt to morph your snippets into well-formed XSLT code, the variable has type `element()*` though for me.

Comment: Still facing the same issue can please take a look at the screen shots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zRcu2mgOnYEg3aGniVaOTZj4FlY55mMY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In my sample and in the one you currently have in your question here on StackOverflow the variable declaration uses `<xsl:variable name="var-name" select="function-call(...)"/>` e.g. `<xsl:variable name="entityIdList" select="cdocfx:createEntityIdList(n:report/n:format-inputs)"/>`. As far as I can see in your screenshoots in that code you wrongly use `<xsl:variable name="var-name"><xsl:value-of select="function-call()"/></xsl:variable>` instead.

Comment: So that is the place you have to fix as with that form you will always create a document node or fragment node containing a text node with the string value of the function call result.

Comment: yes in the caller of the function there was <xsl:value-of .......> this was converting to document node and i chnaged to <xsl:copy-of...> its working as expected the list is of type element()". Appreciate your help on this